# Http Service Not Updating Select Boxes with New Data

Tags: .net, angularjs

this.set_opportunity  is a function in the angular service:

```
calculator_app.service('FillOpportunity', function () {
    this.fill_opportunity = function (path,$scope,$http) {

        $http.get($scope.servername + 'calculator/getproducts?idstring=' + path).then(function (response) {
            $scope.opportunity_data = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {

        });
    };

    this.update_logs = function ($scope,data) {

    };

    this.set_opportunity = function ($http,$scope,url,$timeout) {
        $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.incremental_revenues = response.data[0];
                $scope.contributions = response.data[1];
                console.log($scope.contributions);
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 500);

        }).catch(function (response) {

        });
    };
```

on click of a button on a dialog, the set_session function will be called:
set_session function will call the set_opportunity function.

```
$scope.set_session = function (record) {

        $scope.display_opportunities_dialog.close();
        var id = record[0];
        var name = record[1];
        var c_ir = record[6];
        var c_c = record[7];
        var t_ir = record[8];
        var t_c = record[9];

        var url = $scope.servername + '/calculator/getrecordsforsession?id=' + id;
        FillOpportunity.set_opportunity($http,$scope,url,$timeout);
    };
```

set opportunity sets the following scope variables as shown:

```
$scope.incremental_revenues = response.data[0];
 $scope.contributions = response.data[1];
```

These are models for the select boxes in the same page.

```
    <select id="sel_contributions" ng-model="contribution_selected" ng-options="a for a in contributions" 
                            multiple="" style="height:300px;overflow-x:scroll" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"></select>

 <select id="sel_incremental_revenue" ng-model="incremental_revenue_selected" ng-options="a for a in incremental_revenues" 
                            name="selproducttype" multiple="" style="height:300px;overflow-x:scroll" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched"></select>
```

The service retuns the new data and sets the scope variable but the select box shows no data.

Comment: what value do you want to show in the dropdown?

Comment: Also are you positive it returning array data sources an not object data sources?

Comment: incremental_revenues is a javascript array and that is a list of strig returned from c# converted to json

Comment: Can you provide use with some mock data in the same format?

Comment: ["[test] $47,945.73 = 1,560 Cases @ $30.73 per case.… Adult | Tube Feed | Core | 1.5 kcal | Home Care]", "[test] $47,945.73 = 1,560 Cases @ $30.73 per case.… Adult | Tube Feed | Core | 1.5 kcal | Home Care]"]

Comment: this is for incremental_revenue which I am getting after the http get call from service

Comment: Ok. are you just saying it won't load the slect with data? http://plnkr.co/edit/u1dtFeedhd55t8VRGDdY?p=preview

Comment: hi. thanks, initially it is loading. but when I call a service on some button click, get the new data and assigning the scope variable in hope that the select boxes refresh. it is not refreshning.

Comment: I don't get what you need and will be leaving soon, but please isolate the button click that not refreshing the scope. Maybe make it a jsbin/plunkr?. I think the question needs more background details and someone will help.

Comment: i am doing the same thing instead i am calling http get in set_data and set the result set to scope variable which is not working...http://plnkr.co/edit/iKZDC2zMWKXk755MBfPL?p=preview

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i thought this would have been answered by now, check out my answer below.

Comment: For the benefit of others, I got the solution for this. There was nothing wrong with the code. The popup from which I cam calling the clickevent(ngDialog) has a div with ng-controller="Calculator". So as the button from which I cam calling the click event inside this, angular is somehow confused with the scopes so it has not updated the original scope data. When I removed the ng-controller="Calcualtor" then the problem was gone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought someone answered this.. you need to update what you're returning from the service.

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);   
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','Fill','$http',function($scope,Fill,$http){
  $scope.clickfunction = function()
    {
      $scope.items = Fill.set_data($scope,$http);
    };
}])
.service('Fill', function () {       
  this.set_data = function ($scope,$http) {
    return $http.get("data.json").then(function (response) {
      return response.data;                
    });
  }        
});
```